# Implementing fminunc function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Are there Fminunc function in Tensorflow? I'm trying to make my model converge faster and thought I would be able to use fminunc function as in Matlab. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html)

However I didn't find a built-in fminunc function in Tensorflow...Maybe I'm missing it. Could people give a description of its implementation or what is it called in Tensorflow if there exists a similar one under disguise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to call out to a separate non-linear programming solver to solve a minimization problem (which it appears is what fminunc does) from Tensorflow.

However, in some sense, finding minima of functions is precisely what Tensorflow's optimizers do (e.g., GradientDescentOptimizer), although using a different class of algorithms (stochastic gradient descent) that are tuned for Neural Network applications.

It's hard to say more without more information about what you are trying to do.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I think that did! Thanks!